# Help identifying this variation of a Molex or Amp connector please!

Tags: connector, plug, identification

My very first post!  I've researched to the point of despair (digikey, mouser, amp, molex, others...) trying to identify this variation of your everyday 4-pin, 2-row molex pin plug.

An easily findable version has your expected square plastic molex "pins" that house the actual crimped pins, with what one might call the "upper left" and "lower right" being tombstone shaped rather than square to enforce polarization.

I'm working with an old discontinued piece of LED stage lighting equipment with a variation of that that is polarized differently, and I can't find the connector anywhere.

I *might* have found the connector here or there, but the information that explains HOW a version of your typical molex connector is polarized is pretty well ignored in specs and descriptions it seems, and as for photos so many of the online resources only show stock photos rather than a specific photo of the exact connector.

Attachments and images to clarify my need.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: drawing of what I've found vs. what I need]

[image: the connector I need to identify and purchase a bunch of...]

[image: the board mounted vertical receptacles to plug into...]

Comment: My advice, just get a standard polarised connector, and use a knife to shave the corners off the bottom left pin.

Comment: Yep, that should work. Or you can buy whatever Molex sells now with same pitch (looks like Mini-Fit Jr. series to me) and replace both plug and socket.

Comment: if you only need to replace the contacts, then reuse the shell .... otherwise, you could replace the whole connector

Comment: you may be able to pull the shell off the soldered pins and push on another shell

Comment: these are things I considered doing, but unfortunately I need to create additional parts to go with existing parts (which is fine for the shaving down squares approach admittedly), but also work with other existing parts with the board mounted connector that I can't change (I can take my gear apart and alter it no problem, but probably not a rental! :P )

Comment: I wonder if it's just a manufacturer I haven't thought of yet...who else makes Molex type connectors?

Answer (score 2):

It's a TE Connectivity Mate-n-lok 794805-1 [image: 794805-1]

Comment: OOH! OOH!  OH my gosh thank you so much!  I think I'm going to really like these forums. :)